# How to open gallery in android device through xamarin.forms app?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-gallery

I am working on xamarin.forms app. I created a xaml page in Global folder. I have a button on the page. I want to open the gallery of android device on click of that button. So I created a method in MainActivity.cs in Android folder.  But I don't know how to access this method from button click event from xaml.cs page. I tried to create an object of MainActivity and access the method with the object. But getting null reference exception on "StartActivityForResult". following is my code. Please tell me how I can access the gallery open method in xamarin.forms.
My code is below that I am using to open gallery in MainActivity.cs class:

```
   public void ImagePicker()
    {
        try
        {
            var imageIntent = new Intent ();
            imageIntent.SetType ("image/*");
            imageIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple,true);
            imageIntent.SetAction (Intent.ActionGetContent);
            this.StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if ((requestCode == 0) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
        {

        }
    }
```

Regards,
Anand Dubey

Comment: to access a native android function from a shared Forms page, you will need to use DependencyService: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Comment: I created my own function in MainActivity ImagPicker(). I am able to call it via Dependency service, but in line this.StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0); I am getting NullReferenceException. What may be the reason, that it is giving me null reference exception.

Comment: Which specific value is null?

Comment: I am not getting any value null in StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0); But after executing this line I am getting Java.lang.NullReferenceException. Can you tell me in Intent what value I should bind for multiple image selection. I tried Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple true but its not working. Do you have any idea about this?